# Почему функция insertBefore добавляет элемент не туда, куда я хочу?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Коллеги, есть такой пример (далее опишу проблему в комментариях в коде):

```js
//Код ниже работает, но почему то не верно
// DIV добавляется после SPAN
//  но если раскомментировать  закомментированные строки
//
// то работает, но DIV добавляется только в первый элемент
const li = document.querySelectorAll('li'),
  //span = document.querySelector('span'),  //раскоментировать
  span = document.querySelectorAll('span'), // закоментировать
  bg = document.createElement('div');

li.forEach(s => {
  s.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let bg_passive = bg.cloneNode();
    bg_passive.className = 'bg-passive';

    if (s.childNodes.length <= 1) {
      //s.insertBefore(bg_passive, span); // раскоментировать
      s.insertBefore(bg_passive, s.span); // закоментировать
      console.log(s.childNodes);

    }

  })
})
```

```css
li {
  width: 30px;
  height: 100%;
  list-style: none;
}

span {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<menu>
  <li><span>1</span></li>
  <li><span>2</span></li>
  <li><span>3</span></li>
  <li><span>4</span></li>
  <li><span>5</span></li>
  <li><span>6</span></li>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё там правильно!

`document.querySelector('span')` - выбирает только 1-ый `span` в документе.
`document.querySelectorAll('span')` - выбирает все `span`-ы в документе.

Если функции `insertBefore` передавать один и тот же `span`, то она и будет им пользоваться.

Если хотите, чтобы работало так, как вы хотите, то замените строку:

`s.insertBefore(bg_passive, span);`

на

`s.insertBefore(bg_passive, s.firstChild);`

**Добавлено 2 часа спустя:**

Если же строку ту всё же оставить как
`s.insertBefore(bg_passive, s.span);`, то поскольку `s.span = undefined`, то [согласно документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore), вставляемый элемент вставляется в конец списка дочерних элементов. Именно поэтому во втором случае вам кажется, что там правильно, но на самом деле там надо передавать `s.firstChild`, чтобы было так,  как вы хотите.

Comment: Я хватаю `span` так  `span = document.querySelectorAll('span')`...  При чем тут первый элемент...???  `DIV` - должен добавляться перед `span`, а он вставляет после...  Как правильно реализовать я знаю и давно уже написал как надо... Меня интересует почему именно вот в данном примере `div` вставляется не туда куда указано в коде...

Comment: @Air Вы же указали,что надо закоментировать

Comment: @Air если оставить как есть, s.span undefined,поэтому в конец списка дочерних

Comment: @Air, вы же написали, что `span = document.querySelector('span'),  //раскоментировать`, а `span = document.querySelectorAll('span'), // закоментировать`? Так? Не я же это писал! И если так сделать, то будет только первый элемент, который вы постоянно  передаёте.

Comment: Все верно...  Просто спать надо чаще и побольше...)))  Я вообще забыл про коллекцию, индексы и не мог понять разницы между моим правильным кодом и этим кривым... Благодарю, ты меня навел на правильную мысль...

Comment: @Air, да, сон - это важная вещь! Бывает! ;-) Очень советую послушать [про распорядок дня и важность сна](https://youtu.be/n0k2xx_7b9w). Не пожалеете!

Answer (score 1):

Да криво реализовано вообще, вот так всё работает. Без лишних велосипедов,а вообще это всё действие можно до 3-х строчек кода сжать на JQ.

```js
//Код ниже работает, но почему то не верно
// DIV добавляется после SPAN
//  но если раскомментировать  закомментированные строки
//
// то работает, но DIV добавляется только в первый элемент
const li = document.querySelectorAll('li'),
  span = document.querySelector('span'),  //раскоментировать
  bg = document.createElement('div');

li.forEach(s => {
  s.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let bg_passive = bg.cloneNode();
    bg_passive.className = 'bg-passive';
console.log(s.childNodes);
    if (s.childNodes.length <= 1) {
      s.insertBefore(bg_passive, event.target); // раскоментировать
      console.log(s.childNodes);
    }
  })
})
```

```css
li {
  width: 30px;
  height: 100%;
  list-style: none;
}

span {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<menu>
  <li><span>1</span></li>
  <li><span>2</span></li>
  <li><span>3</span></li>
  <li><span>4</span></li>
  <li><span>5</span></li>
  <li><span>6</span></li>
</menu>
```

Comment: Каких 3-х строчек кода?! В jQuery [БОЛЕЕ 10.000 строк кода](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js)!!! Считайте внимательно!

Comment: @Bharata вы издеваетесь, я говорю о том что данные действия можно уместить в 3 строчки используя JQ библиотеку. На нативном ясно что короче будет без подгрузки библиотеки.)) Чем проще - тем лучше. Зачем столько действий ?)

Comment: Ну так и не пишите 3 строчки! НЕ МЕНЕЕ 10.003 строк кода! НЕ МЕНЕЕ! И я не издеваюсь! В свою очередь мне кажется, что издеваетесь вы, когда пишете о 3 строчках кода. Ладно, замяли. Просто, пожалуйста, не пишите о 3 строчках кода, ибо это неправда.

Comment: Теперь я знаю,что в jQuery не 3 строчки...=))

Comment: @Bharata вы придираетесь к словам! Вы прекрасно поняли что на JQ реализация данного велосипеда была бы более лаконична и заключалась бы в написании 3-х строк ! Вы не путайте функц. программирование с тем что реализация сего занимает 3 строки с использованием JQ библиотеки, не берём в счёт что JQ занимает разное количество строк в зависимости от версий, от минимизации файлов и.т.д. Вот теперь замяли.